# table column width is not increare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, css, html5-canvas

There is an issue to  increase table column width of a particular column...

```
  <table id="metadata">            
    <tr>
      <td class="meta-head">GRN #</td>
      <% if @grn.date.month >= 4 && @grn.date.month <= 12 %>
        <td>
          <textarea><%= "GRN"+@warehouse.shortform+"/"+(@grn.date.year.to_s.at(2..3))+"-"+(((@grn.date.year)+1).to_s.at(2..3))+"/"+(@grn.serial.to_s.rjust(5, '0')) %>
          </textarea>
        </td>
      <% else %>
        <td><textarea><%= "GRN"+@warehouse.shortform+"/"+(((@grn.date.year)-1).to_s.at(2..3))+"-"+(@grn.date.year.to_s.at(2..3))+"/"+(@grn.serial.to_s.rjust(5, '0')) %></textarea></td>
      <% end %>
      <td class="meta-head">Vehicle</td>
      <td><textarea id="date"><%= @grn.vehicle_no  %></textarea></td>
      <td rowspan="3" style="border:none; width: 200px;">
        <div id="logo">
          <div id="logohelp">
            <input id="imageloc" type="text" size="50" value="" /><br>
                (max width: 540px, max height: 100px)
          </div>
         <% if @warehouse.logo != nil %>
           <%= image_tag(@warehouse.logo, :alt => "logo", id: "image") %><br>
         <% else %>
         <% end %>
       </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="meta-head">GRN Date</td>
     <td><textarea id="date"><%= @grn.date.strftime("%d/%m/%y")  %></textarea></td>
     <td class="meta-head">Bill #</td>
     <td><textarea id="date"><%= @grn.bill_no  %></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="meta-head">Challan</td>
     <td><textarea id="date">No. <%= @grn.challan_no  %>,   Dt.   <%= @grn.challan_date  %></textarea></td>
     <td class="meta-head">Bill Date</td>
     <td><textarea id="date"><%= @grn.bill_date  %></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="meta-head">PO #</td>
     <td><textarea id="date"><%=    @grnitems[0].purchase_order_item.purchaseorder.serial  %></textarea></td>
     <td class="meta-head">Transporter</td>
     <td><textarea id="date"><%= @grn.transporter  %></textarea></td>
     <td rowspan="3" style="border:none; width: 200px;">
     <% if @warehouse.address1 != nil %>
       <h6>  <%=  @warehouse.address1 %> 
         <%=  @warehouse.address2 %> 
         <%=  @warehouse.address3 %> 
         <%=  @warehouse.address4 %> </h6>
         <% end %>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="meta-head">Vendor </td>
     <td><textarea id="date"><%=    @grnitems[0].purchase_order_item.purchaseorder.vendor.description  %></textarea>  </td>
     <td class="meta-head">LR #</td>
     <td><textarea id="date"><%= @grn.lr_no  %></textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="meta-head">Way bill </td>
     <td><textarea id="date"></textarea></td>
     <td class="meta-head">LR Date</td>
     <td><textarea id="date"><%= @grn.lr_date  %></textarea></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

my table like 
[image]

i like to implement thelogo and  address column are increase as per content.
I am trying various way like

```
<table id="metadata" width="100%" >
<td width="100%">
```

I dont know where i mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this style attribute for no word wrapping:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```